# What does the blobby icon in Hexcells Infinite do?

Tags: hexcells-infinite

On the initial screen of Hexcells Infinite, there are 3 icons in the lower left-hand corner:

[image: Hexcells Infinite menu icons]

The first one on the left controls music & sound effects, the middle one lets you swap what the mouse buttons do, but what does the third one do?  It's normally white and almost invisible, but it becomes the gray blob pictured when you move the mouse over it.  Clicking it toggles an outline around it, but surely it does more than that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It toggles an outline for the blue counter zones.  The "there are this many blue cells within 2 cells of this one" zone hint, that's introduced in 4-1.

Screenshots below, first showing zone without the highlight, second showing zone with the normal highlight, and third showing it with the border.

[image: Unhilighted zone][image][image: Screenshot showing border]

Took me a bit to tinker with the game and find out what it was doing.  Wish I'd noticed that earlier, would've saved a lot of squinting!